# Boolean expression simplified

Tags: boolean-algebra

c.  Interpret the following complex Boolean expression and produce a truth table and a logic circuit?

---

---

(x+y•x) + (x•y)

**.**=AND
+=or

Answer (score 0):

If the dot is "and" then $(x+yx) +xy \stackrel{xy=yx}{=} x(1+y)+xy \stackrel{1+y=1}{=} x+xy = x(1+y) = x$